# Save Acrobat PDF with Stamps and Added Text as Base Document

Tags: pdf

I added a couple of stamps and Textboxes to my PDF document in Acrobat.  I want to save the PDF but have the new stamps and Textboxes be added to the base document.  I don't want them to be clicked on and have the stamp be selected nor the Textboxes.  How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have editing permission to the PDF, you should be able to save it.  If you don't, however, you're limited to what you can do with the comment tools in Acrobat (assuming that's what you're using to edit the PDF).

Comment: I have full editing capabilities for the PDF.  I am using Acrobat.  What I want to do is incorporate what I add to the PDF to the base document and not keep them as separate entities for others to select.